# Gesture detector continue pan after rebuild

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

I have a gesture detector that I use for dragging a component. My component can be displayed vertically or horizontally. When it changes from horizontal to vertical display it (logically) rebuild the component. Thus, when the component is rebuilt the drag action is stopped and I need to tap again on the drag area to start the drag. I would like to keep dragging after rebuild.

Here is a gif for a better understanding :

[image]

Here is my widget code :

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class DraggableActionBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget actionBar;

  final bool isDragging;


  final bool displayHorizontally;

  final void Function(DragStartDetails details)? onDragStart;

  final void Function(DragEndDetails details)? onDragEnd;

  final void Function(DragUpdateDetails details)? onDragUpdate;

  const DraggableActionBar({
    required this.actionBar,
    required this.isDragging,
    this.onDragUpdate,
    this.displayHorizontally = true,
    this.onDragEnd,
    this.onDragStart,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(
    BuildContext context,
  ) {
    List<Widget> actions = <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        width: AdaptiveData.getFactorizedSize(factor: 6),
        height: AdaptiveData.getFactorizedSize(factor: 6),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onPanUpdate: onDragUpdate,
          onPanStart: onDragStart,
          onPanEnd: onDragEnd,
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.drag_indicator,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      actionBar,
    ];

    late Widget actionDisplay;

    if (displayHorizontally) {
      actionDisplay = Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: actions,
      );
    } else {
      actionDisplay = Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: actions,
      );
    }

    Widget widgetToReturn = Card(
      elevation: isDragging ? 32 : null,
      color: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.backgroundColor,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(
          AdaptiveData.getFactorizedSpace(),
        ),
        child: actionDisplay,
      ),
    );

    return widgetToReturn;
  }

}
```

I can't think of a solution that behave display correctly without rebuild and I can't see a solution that would keep dragging after state is updated. Have you any solution for that ?